# How can I create a trait/type to unify iterating over some set of integers from either a Range or a Vec?

Tags: rust, traits

I need the trait `XYZ` to define a method that allows iterating over some set of integers.  This set of integers is defined either by a backing `Vec` or by a `Range<usize>`.  However, I run into various (lifetime or type) issues depending on how I define the `XYZIterator` type that is supposed to unify these `Iterator`s over `Vec`/`Range`.

The backup solution would be to allocate and return `Vec`s, but I wondered whether there was a way without cloning/allocating memory.

```rust
type XYZIterator = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>;

trait XYZ {
    fn stuff(&self) -> XYZIterator;
}

struct Test {
    objects: Vec<usize>,
}
impl XYZ for Test {
    fn stuff(&self) -> XYZIterator {
        Box::new(self.objects.iter())
    }
}

struct Test2 {}
impl XYZ for Test2 {
    fn stuff(&self) -> XYZIterator {
        Box::new((1..4).into_iter())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t1 = Test {
        objects: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };
    let t2 = Test2 {};

    t1.stuff().for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
    t2.stuff().for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
    t1.stuff()
        .filter(|x| x % 2 == 0)
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
    t2.stuff()
        .filter(|x| x % 2 == 0)
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
}
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, usize> as Iterator>::Item == usize`
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         Box::new(self.objects.iter())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found reference
   |
   = note:   expected type `usize`
           found reference `&usize`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Iterator<Item = usize>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

1. In the implementation of `XYZ` for `Test1`, you return the iterator `self.objects.iter()`. `Vec::iter` iterates over *references* to the objects, not objects themselves, so this is an iterator over `&usize`, which doesn't match the return type. You should have gotten an error about this. It's easy to fix though: `self.objects.iter().copied()` will copy each element out of the reference.
2. In `type XYZIterator = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize>>;`, since there is no lifetime in the trait object, it defaults to 'static - that is, your iterator can live forever. But that's not the case with the vector iterator - it has a reference to the vector is iterating over. This is where you are having lifetime issues.

   The solution is to give the `XYZIterator` type a lifetime:

   ```
   type XYZIterator<'a> = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = usize> + 'a>;
   ```

   And alter the traits and trait implementations to use the lifetime.

Also consider altering your type or function to accept any `T: Iterator<Item=usize>`; it will then accept any iterator that produces `usize`s

Comment: The `+ 'a` was the key thing I was missing, thanks alot!